# Why does "Endgame​" have its particular time travel theory?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

I understood the time travel theory used in *Avengers: Endgame*. But why did the Russo brothers choose that theory? I mean all the famous time travel movies told us different theories.

Is it because it cannot damage other timelines currently present in MCU? Or is there something else and specific reason behind it?

Comment: It let them put in the funny line about sci-fi lying about how time travel worked.

Comment: **Rule of cool**.  You think I'm kidding! It made a better story.

Comment: that's just lazy writing !

Comment: It's not a new theory. There's probably hundreds of approaches to time travel in sci-fi (and fantasy). Heck, Terminator itself had three different approaches in the first three movies :D The concept of alternate timelines is important in the comic Marvel universe, at least; if you count that Spiderman movie, that too.

Comment: Time travel is not a real thing that exists. Why use _any_ theory over any other? It doesn't really matter which you use as long as it's consistent.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As a quick answer, the Russo's along with writers Markus and McFeely stated on the feature commentary that one of the main choices for the use of the particular time travel apparatus was simply due to the fact that its inception was already pre - figured in the plot, thanks to Peyton Reeds *Ant-Man* films which both set up the notion and mechanics of the 'Quantum Realm'.

Following consultations with actual theorists, they settled on the choice due to both the above and also the notion that the method removed grandfather paradoxes and the like, allowing for the mid - point reintroduction of the 2014 Thanos, Nebula and Gamora and all sorts of similar silliness without the audience picking up or pulling on too many exposed plot threads which, like any other time travel movie, naturally make less and less sense the more the viewer looks into them.

Comment: yeah that makes sense. as they want to end the 10year running saga.

Comment: Just to add onto this, the chosen theory also conforms to the [Marvel Multiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse_(Marvel_Comics)#List_of_main_alternate_Earths_and_universes). I know it's just a catch-all ability for writers to use different universes in different stories, but it's nice to see that Endgame didn't particularly contradict the existence of these alternate universes.